# How can I update form on resize on 64-bit window?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-2007

I have a problem with contents on a form is not updated correct when running in 64-bit window like Windows Server 2003 or 2008. There is a short video that illustrate this at [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/ht3bhcnDd).

When I resize the main window the content is not repainted. But if I change the small splitter it is repainted. And everything works perfect on a 32-bit Windows.
I have not made any OnResize events for this.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: Yes, the executable is 32-bit. It is only the Windows OS that is 64-bit.

Comment: No reason why it should behave differently on 64 bit OS. I've never seen such problems on 64 bit OS.

Comment: Maybe a wrong cast (32/64-bit mismatch) somewhere in a message handler (WM_SIZE, ...) in one of the used components?

Comment: @ulrich it's d2007 and so is a 32 bit process

Comment: I'd suspect the graphics driver on the server. They are often poor.

Comment: From the screencast it doesn't look like only a painting problem. I believe @Lars got it right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by having to many nested controls/windows. The stack size of 64bit Windows is smaller than on 32bit. This gets even smaller if there are global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hooks. The `WM_SIZE` message event handling gets a stack overflow which the Windows kernel eats. See [here](http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/toolbar2000/msg07779.html) and a fix [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25646). Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355258/delphi-7-forms-anchors-not-working-in-vista) for the same problem.

PS: WinForms also suffer from the [same](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934) [problem](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=alejacma&y=2008&m=11&d=20&WeblogPostName=controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64&GroupKeys).

Comment: First answer that seems to be real, thanks. We will investigate this.